# How is character star handled in a resource bundle

Tags: java, resourcebundle

If we use `"*"` as part of the resource bundle, the character gets removed during the message formatting process (java.util.ResourceBundle). How are we supposed to escape this character?

Comment: What do you mean by message formatting process?

Comment: Show some example. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: How do you write a * b {0} - seems to fail

Comment: How do you write a X b {0} - seems to work

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using \* or the Unicode escapes form - \u002A

EDIT: Seems that to display \* in answer here you need to type \\*.

Comment: I am wondering why * has to be escaped? The bundles are saved in latin-1 encoding and the codepoint supports *

Comment: I have stublmed on this proble a while back, and never manage to find any documentation explaining why.